# Add attribute to xml element not allowed in DTD

Tags: java, xml

I have to use a external DTD, that specifies that a certain element can only have id attribute:

```
<!ELEMENT x (y | z)>
<!ATTLIST x id ID #IMPLIED>
```

So something like this is valid

```
<x id="x">...</x>
```

But if i try something like this:

```
<x id="x" custom="custom">...</x>
```

My parser gives me the following error:

```
Attribute "custom" must be declared for element type "x".
```

So I understand what the error says and why its happening, but as i said the DTD is external and sadly i cant change it. Is there a workaround or a hack that can use to add my own custom attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either disable DTD validation in your parser, or try defining [internal DTD](https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_internal_dtd.cfm).

Comment: Can internal and external be used at the same time and have the internal override a certain part of the extarnal one?

Comment: @user1985273: Yes you can do that.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i needed. Added following to my DOCTYPE and it worked: <!ATTLIST x id ID #IMPLIED custom CDATA #IMPLIED>